# Referencing class lib from a DNX project, does not update reference after class lib changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dnx

I have a DNX 451 website in 1 solution, and a common class lib in another solution.
I reference the common lib from my DNX website. I just 'add reference' and 'browse' to find the bin folder of the common lib.

This works fine on the first go, but when I make changes to the common lib and rebuild, the DNX reference is not updated. Both the wrap-files and the \lib\dnx451-files that has the common.dll remain unchanged.

Currently the only way to see the changes is to manually delete all traces of the common.dll and add it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should not be doing that (wrapping a dll file that changes in time), it is rather an anti-pattern.

Some ideas:

- Add this project to your web solution and then add reference to a project (not dll) (recommended)
- Publish you project as nuget and then reference nuget package

You can also just write a prebuild script that could update the dll manually. Some sample can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/ec2d86cead2f815117d7759d7ca644dc4256616f/src/Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost/project.json)

Comment: Thanks ill give it a try